# SharePoint Get Item Metadata Server Side

Tags: 2013, powershell

I try to get all "Homepages/Welcome Pages" recursive in my SharePoint 2013.
I got that.

```
    param($url = $(Read-Host -prompt "Enter Root Site Collection Path"))

#Get the PowerShell Snapin
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

#Get Root Site
$root = Get-SPSite $url

#If site was found / valid
if($root -ne $null)
{

     foreach($subSite in $root.AllWebs)
      {
                Write-Host $subSite.Title -ForegroundColor Magenta
                Write-Host $subSite.Url -ForegroundColor Cyan
                Write-Host $subSite.RootFolder.WelcomePage -ForegroundColor Red
                $WelcomePage = $subSite.RootFolder.WelcomePage
                $file = $subSite.RootFolder.Fields
       $subSite.Dispose()
      }

        $root.Dispose()

}
```

Now I need all Metadata Information for each of these Pages.
But I don't know how to get the information from a File now :/

Comment: $file.Item will bring you the SPListItem-Object of the file which holds the metadata informations. Take care, you wrote "$file = $subSite.RootFolder.Fields". From my understanding you want to retrive the Files not the Fields :)

Comment: $file = $subSite.RootFolder.Files is empty.
And even if it wouldn't be, it would give me all files instead of only the "Homepage"...
I Need only the Metadata from from the WelcomePage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Problem! 
My Code above gave me the Server Relative Url of all Welcome Pages.
With that I got all the Metadata I wanted from each Welcome Page:

```
param($url = $(Read-Host -prompt "Enter Root Site Collection Path"))

#Get the PowerShell Snapin
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"`

#Get Root Site
$root = Get-SPSite $url`

#If site was found / valid
if($root -ne $null)
{
    foreach($subSite in $root.AllWebs)
{
    Write-Host $subSite.Title -ForegroundColor Magenta
    Write-Host $subSite.Url -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Write-Host $subSite.RootFolder.WelcomePage -ForegroundColor Red
    $WelcomePage = $subSite.RootFolder.WelcomePage
    Write-Host $subSite.GetFile($WelcomePage).Item.[MYMETADATUM]
    $subSite.Dispose()
}
    $root.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: If this answers the original question, please mark it as the answer.